# Why I have the gradient on this button on IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, gradient

I have a red button. When I click on this, the button becomes blue with a gradient.

I don't understand why, because IE8 doesn't support the gradient in CSS3, isn't it ? 
It's really weird.
The button has **not** the property `background-image: url()`.

Screenshot : http://f.cl.ly/items/2h071c370o3J0R3v0435/cap-blue.jpg

Comment: If there is no css/javascript setting the `background-color` or `background-image`, then it could only be the windows theme doing this. But it doesn't looks like that in this case. It's impossible to say without any code

Comment: Have you checked for filter gradients? Something like `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');`

Comment: Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/cWSSV/ in older IE. It has a gradient without using `background-image: url()`

Comment: Oh yes !!!! this is "filter"... Thank you @Ana